# org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied

Tags: hadoop, hive

My application executes a hive query by using hive-jdbc, but I get the following exception.

```
Failed to open new session: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=anonymous, access=EXECUTE, inode="/tmp/hive-suser":suser:supergroup:drwxrwx---
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirStatAndListingOp.getFileInfo(FSDirStatAndListingOp.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:3861)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getFileInfo(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1006)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
```

But my /tmp/hive-suser permission is

```
"drwxrwxrwx - suser supergroup 0 2017-09-07 21:58 /tmp/hive-suser"
```

Why is the permission different?
Why would an exception error occur?

Comment: Shawn, I had same error and search for hours to find solution. Finally I got what I was missing in my connection string need to add UID=user_Name and set AuthMech=2. That will resolve your error hopefully as in you question I can easily see Access denied for anonymous user. Hoping this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

user=anonymous

You are not authenticated as either `suser` or a part of the `supergroup` group

The permissions are set to `drwxrwx---`, so I'm not sure how you checked that otherwise, but it means nobody but the user or group can access